# How to make transition between emoji keyboard and soft keyboard?

Tags: android, emoji, soft-keyboard

I am working on an android instant chat application. I have successfully implemented the basic functionality of it. Now I have added a panel of emoticons using the library `compile 'com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:1.3.3'`. I am using FrameLayout in my XML file for displaying the emoticons.

**1. activity_chat.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FCAB26"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".60"
        android:background="@null"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"></ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSmile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_msg_panel_smiles"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10sp"/>

        <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:layout_weight=".60"></com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Send Message" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/emojicons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here even after specifying the visibility as gone, FrameLayout is occupying some space.

The code which is displaying a panel of emoticons through the above-mentioned library is given below :

```
 // This method will set a panel of emoticons in the fragment
private void setEmojiconFragment(boolean useSystemDefault) {
    // Replacing the existing fragment having id emojicons with the fragment of emoticons library containing emoticons
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.emojicons, EmojiconsFragment.newInstance(useSystemDefault)).commit();
}
```

**3.Screenshot**

[image]

As u can see in the screenshot, I have a *ImageView*, an *EditText* and send message button. On clicking *ImageView*, emoji panel is displayed and on clicking EditText emoji keyboard is hidden and soft keyboard is displayed.The following code handles this.

**Showing emoji popup:**

```
public void showEmojiPopUp(boolean showEmoji) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**hiding softkeyboard:**

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

My problem is that I want emoji keyboard and soft keyboard to occupy equal space. At a time only one should be visible.I  want to make the transition between emoji keyboard and soft keyboard. As u can see in the code, I am adding the emoji keyboard in the *FrameLayout* . I am not able to make the size of soft keyboard and emoji keyboard equal here. Please help me to fix the issue.

**Edited Code:**
I have made some changes in my code:

**showEmojiPopUp() method**: Here we are adjusting the height of FrameLayout containing a panel of emoticons so that the height of *softkeyboard* and emoji keyboard is same.

```
 public void showEmojiPopUp(boolean showEmoji) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    deviceHeight = size.y;
    Log.e("Device Height", String.valueOf(deviceHeight));
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (deviceHeight / 2.5); // Setting the height of FrameLayout
    frameLayout.requestLayout();
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    hideKeyboard();
}
```

**2. hideKryboard() method**

```
// Hiding the keyboard
public void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

It is working for me now.

Comment: hi...have you find any solution? i have the same problem

Comment: Please tell me whether it is working for you or not.

Comment: well i have used some different code...but the logic is same

Comment: @HRaval : Are you able to send emoji to different device.I am encoding emoticon to unicode character using String toServer = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message); i am decoding using String messageReceived = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicodeMessageReceived); Now i am displaying the unicode through EmojiconTextView.But it is not converting the unicode into corresponding image .Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103674/discussion-between-h-raval-and-deepakr).

Answer (score 1):

i am using this code which i found from here....[link](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/tree/master/example)

```
 public Spannable parse(String text) {
        CharSequence fromCache = cache.get(text);
        if (fromCache != null) {
            return (Spannable) fromCache;
        } else {
            CharSequence parsed = emoji.replaceEmoji(text);
            Matcher matcher = userReference.matcher(text);
            Spannable s;
            if (parsed instanceof Spannable) {
                s = (Spannable) parsed;
            } else {
                s = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(parsed);
            }

            while (matcher.find()) {
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff427ab0), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            }
            cache.put(text, s);

            return s;
        }
    }
```